# How to change code generation settings in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, autocomplete, auto-generate

I have the following variables in an object:

```
private String mName;
private String mArtist;
private String mWhosampledPage;
private String mImage;
private List<Pair<String, String>> mSamples;
private List<Pair<String, String>> mSampledIn;
private List<Pair<String, String>> mCovers;
private List<Pair<String, String>> mRemixes;
```

I want to use Alt+Insert in IntelliJ to auto generate a constructor and when I do that, this is what gets generated:

```
public Song(String mName, String mArtist, String mWhosampledPage, String mImage, List<Pair<String, String>> mSamples, List<Pair<String, String>> mSampledIn, List<Pair<String, String>> mCovers, List<Pair<String, String>> mRemixes) {
    this.mName = mName;
    this.mArtist = mArtist;
    this.mWhosampledPage = mWhosampledPage;
    this.mImage = mImage;
    this.mSamples = mSamples;
    this.mSampledIn = mSampledIn;
    this.mCovers = mCovers;
    this.mRemixes = mRemixes;
}
```

How can I change the generate settings such that the constructor created looks more like this:

```
public Song(String name, String artist, String whosampledPage, String image, List<Pair<String, String>> samples, List<Pair<String, String>> sampledIn, List<Pair<String, String>> covers, List<Pair<String, String>> remixes) {
    mName = name;
    mArtist = artist;
    mWhosampledPage = whosampledPage;
    mImage = image;
    mSamples = samples;
    mSampledIn = sampledIn;
    mCovers = covers;
    mRemixes = remixes;
}
```

I know this is possible as I have made use of it in other IntelliJ configurations (different devices) but I am not sure how to make the switch.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the settings `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java` and under the tab `Code Generation` set the Field Name prefix to `m`.